# delete first column when exported excel or csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, spreadsheet-excel-writer

let's say, I exported my file in excel

**statement Export**

```
ln[] = writer = pd.ExcelWriter("df2018.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("df2018.xlsx", index = false)
df2018.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()

out[] = 
row0  (blank)  kanwil     jan 2018  feb 2018   janfeb 2018 
row1    0      sunarto    45878     545458     5454878
row2    1      hartanto   123456    545454     4444549
row3    2      pemabuk    9547      787896     4579798
```

(if data frame is df2018)

**my expected** :

```
row0  kanwil     jan 2018  feb 2018   janfeb 2018 
row1  sunarto    45878     545458     5454878
row2  hartanto   123456    545454     4444549
row3  pemabuk    9547      787896     4579798
```

i wanna delete first column

i've tried

pd.ExcelWriter("df2018.xlsx", index = false)

but it doesn't work

what should i do if i want to delete first column when i exported csv or excel

**in a fact, i get info from my data frame (df2018) below:**

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 154 entries, 2 to 155
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Kanwil                 149 non-null object
Cabang                 137 non-null object
Income Januari 2018    151 non-null object
Income Febuari 2018    151 non-null object
Income Jan-Feb 2018    151 non-null object
dtypes: object(5)
memory usage: 4.2+ KB
None
```

Comment: If write `DataFrame  df`, what is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: @jezrael <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 154 entries, 2 to 155
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Kanwil                 149 non-null object
Cabang                 137 non-null object
Income Januari 2018    151 non-null object
Income Febuari 2018    151 non-null object
Income Jan-Feb 2018    151 non-null object
dtypes: object(5)
memory usage: 4.2+ KB
None

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need specify parameter `index=False` in [`DataFrame.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
pd.ExcelWriter("df2018.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer, index = False)
```

Comment: If you are using multiindex then this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to like these Reference pandas Excel writer:**

https://pbpython.com/improve-pandas-excel-output.html
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html